# SQL Server Stored Procedure INSERT NVARCHAR(MAX) not saving

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a rather simple SQL Server stored procedure with 2 input parameters, a name which is `nvarchar(100)` and results which is `nvarchar(max)`.

The stored procedure just does an insert - nothing more.

```
INSERT INTO TableX (name, results) 
VALUES (@Name, @Results)
```

Results is a `|` delimited file serialized to a string. Sometimes when this stored procedure is run, the row in the table only has the name and results is blank. No SQL errors. It isn't just because of length of results because some of the calls that work are longer then some of the calls that end up empty. I did catch that some of the entries contain single quotes so I stripped out single quotes and that didn't help.

Any ideas?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[tempdata_SaveMarketStatsToCache]
    (@ScreenName NVARCHAR(100),
     @Results NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO TempData_MarketStatsCache (MarketStatsKey, Results)
    VALUES (@ScreenName, @Results)
END
```

Stored Procedure is called from .NET. SQLDbType.NVarchar with length of -1

UPDATE: I suspect it is the size of the string being passed. The smallest string that is failing is just under 250K characters. This is OK for NVARCHAR(max), but it seems that something happens during the INSERT.

UPDATE 2: Turns out it was an issue with SQL Server Managment Studio. I was right clicking on table and choosing edit 200 rows. That showed the column as empty for the rows with the large results (over 200K characters). If I simply ran a query the column values showed.

Comment: How are you calling your stored procedure? What does the whole procedure look like? What is `LEN(results)` for a "blank" row?

Comment: Are you able to consistently reproduce this with specific input values?

Comment: blank or null? If it's seems blank, perhaps there are leading spaces. Can you post the exact proc and the parameters you use that produce the blank?

Comment: if it seems blank, perhaps there is a leading CR or LF

Comment: Added the stored procedure. The values for the results are rather large. So posting them would be ugly if even allowed.

Comment: Have you tried running sql server profiler and seeing what is getting passed from your program to the stored procedure?

Comment: So also added the Length to the table and see that the results are making it into the Stored Procedure. The length is > 0 yet the results dont show up in the table.

Comment: Kevin. I dont have rights to run SQL Server Profiler on the database.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was a SQL Server Management Studio issue making it seem like data wasnt inserted. See Update 2 in the question.